# Django contains on a many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-filter

I am trying to get a user that has the skills needed for a shift. This means the user needs to have the exact skills or more.

I tried this. But this does not work for relation fields

```
User.objects.filter(skills__contains=skills)
```

The `in` operator also does not work because I need a user that has all the skills and not a user which has a subset of the skills required.

Is there a way to retrieve the user where the asked about skills are a subset of the user skills?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in), and then count if the number of matches is the same as the number of elements in `skills`. We here make the assumption that `skills` contains *unique* elements (so no duplicates). You can first convert the list of skills to a `set` to exclude duplicates.

We can thus filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

User.objects.filter(
    skills__in=skills
).annotate(
    matching_skills=Count('skills')
).filter(
    matching_skills=len(skills)
)
```

Comment: Great solution! I added __gte if the user has more skills than the required skills!

Comment: @JessieLiauwAFong: but due to the filtering, the maximum that will be returned is the number of items in `skills`. But `__gte` of course will not cause harm, since `__exact` is implied by `__gte`.